# Georeferencing elevation raster to old map (not vice verse)

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am making elevation foam molds to then vacu-form printed older maps onto. What I'm running into is the desire to match the elevation data to the older maps instead of distorting the older maps to fit whatever projection I desire. A lot of these older maps have some semblance of the correct projection, but a lot of the times it's really far off anything I can try to replicate. So what I would like to go is georeference the geotiff to the old map. I have the old map brought in, and I am using the GCP's to match the same spots, but when I go to georeference, the elevation data is a tiny dot and doesn't match the GCP points at all. I've used almost all the transformation options in Georeferencer to no avail.
[image: Raster with GCP Points]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think problem is that you don't have a target CRS you could define. Can't you find a projection that is similar to your old map, than georeference the old map to this CRS and afterwards the DEM to the same CRS? I guess you tried to change transformation type to Polynominal2, Polynominal3 and Thin Plate Spline?

Comment: As the term "georeference" says, the process is to assign real-world coordinates in a ceratin CRS to a pixel image/raster. If you assign pixels of your input raster to a destination, this destination has to consist of georeferenced coordinates. If you just load your old map to QGIS, it will be placed anywhere in a corner of the map and completely wrong values get assigned. If the former option proposed above is not an option for you, consider to look for a "warping" option that does not include georeferencing.

Comment: I did find a close CRS, but if I georeferenced the old map to it, it would still distort some of the straight lines and text.

Comment: I currently have the CRS set to ESPG: 26715, which is close, but like I said, when I georeference the old map to it, it's a little bit off and distorts the border text and black rectangle around the map. I did try all the transformation types in the georeferencer with the DEM.

Comment: Can you trying to find out in which projection the old map was created? You could then create maybe a custom CRS in QGIS

Comment: It seems to be a distorted NAD27. I can't find any information about the map aside from it being a Soil Map of the USA from 1931.

Comment: Have a look at history of cartography texts about US maps in the first half of the 20th century and what projections/datums were in use back then. I guess your old map uses one of the standards used in this time, so getting an idea about other maps from the same period could be useful.+

Comment: Yeah, I've searched for about 2 weeks now. All I know it is was based on a 1919 USGS base map. I wish I had more information.

Comment: So the question can be reduced to: in what projection was the 1919 USGS base map created? Seems not so difficult to find out, does it?

Comment: I've been trying on and off for over a week, but I have had no luck. I also have 10 other maps I need to make using unknown projections. But I would really love to know if its possible to georeference a DEM to an old map instead of the other way around.

Comment: As told: than probable have a look for **warping** the DEM, not georeference. Maybe something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692864/image-warping-with-a-polynomial-transformation

Comment: thanks, missed that in your original messages.